# Copy cell value to all cells below it

Tags: vba, excel, copy, cell

I don't know how to write a macro that designates a cell within a column as a "master cell" (editable) copy that cells value to all the cells below it in that column, until it reaches a blank/clear formatted cell in column A.  So I want it to look at column A to know when to stop copying the cell values in whichever column.

That is, Cell "C5" will be a master cell, the macro will copy it's value from "C6:C" but looking at column A's cell values to see if it has nothing in it and there's no formatting such as color fill, etc.  and instead of the macro continuing on in column C to infinity (maximum increment for Excel) it will stop at A column's first blank cell row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Example()
    Dim MasterValue As String
    Dim StopRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    'Get the master value
    MasterValue = Range("C5").Value

    'Get the first blank cell in column A
    StopRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    'Start at row 6 and continue to the "Stop Row"
    For i = 6 To StopRow
        'Set every cell from row 6 in column 3 to the "Master Value"
        Cells(i, 3).Value = MasterValue
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: THanks, that worked great!  Now if A has a blank cell, but has formatting is there a way to either skip the cells in A that have a color format, or check for the first cell in A that has no value or formatting(completely clear)?

Comment: So checking through column A can I check for a blank clear of any conditional formatting for the stoprow that you have?

Comment: Sure, you could use members of Cells.Interior and Cells.FormatConditions to check for this in an If statement.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would write that.  Do I have to check for both Cells.Interior and Cells.FormatConditions?

Comment: The comments section isn't really the place for this sort of discussion and this website isn't a place to make program requests. If you are interested in learning you should make an attempt at this yourself and if you get stuck ask a question here. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737%28v=office.14%29.aspx) is a great place to get started!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34106/discussion-between-ripster-and-cheapkid1)