# vba how to check if a cell has no formatting or color

Tags: vba, if-statement, cell, conditional-formatting

I recently had a question regarding how to copy a cell value into all cells below it and stop based on when column A got to a blank cell.  [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843905/vba-macro-copy-cell-value-to-all-cells-below-it)

The excel sheet I'm working in has many divider rows that are color filled across the entire row to separate categories as you scroll down the sheet.  I would like to be able to skip these separating rows in column A when the macro checks for a blank cell in column A.  Or I would like to just assign StopRow to the first cell which has no formatting/no color/no value.

Here is what I have, thanks to Ripster earlier today, but I've failed incorporating a proper if then statement with what he came up with.

```
 Sub Example()
    Dim MasterValue As String
    Dim StopRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    'Get the master value
    MasterValue = Range("C5").Value

    'Get the first blank cell in column A
    StopRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    'Start at row 6 and continue to the "Stop Row"
    For i = 6 To StopRow
        'Set every cell from row 6 in column 3 to the "Master Value"
        Cells(i, 3).Value = MasterValue
    Next
End Sub
```

Please help.
[image: IE]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This took me a while but I found solution to your problem ;)

If macro goes to cell with different color - checking and do nothin, next "i" is taken. This should do what u want. It's possible to add more color ;)

Link to colors - http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm

```
Sub Example()

For i = 6 To 1200
    If Cells(i, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 1 Then 'here is color black

    Else
        If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) = True Then 'if cells in column "A" is empty then stop
            Exit For

        Else
        Cells(i, 3).Value = Range("C5").Value
        End If

   End If

Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: Instead of using x, I need something that stops at the last cell in column A, so if A has cells 1 thru 13 that have values, and row 14 is a color divider row, and A has cells 15 thru 25 with more values, that means I would want the macro to stop copying the master value in column C at the row that A has no value and no background color(both conditions) or Row 26.  With just picking a number for x that means I'll have to update x every time the excel sheet changes...any thoughts?

Comment: Okay, it's kinda hard for me to understand what you wrote, so let's try to analize it step by step. 
You said you want to copy master value all the way down in column C with some conditions:
1. if there is colored background, copying skips
2. if there is no value in column A in the same row, copying stops

Did I understand you correctly? If yes that should be easy ;)

Comment: Try updated code now ;) Ah... and of course you can add functionality of Application.ScreenUpdating = true / false to make it faster ;)

Comment: I tried the new code and still stops at the grey row instead of skipping the grey row and continuing...

Comment: Of course it does, I don't know what colour you got in your sheet. That's why I gave you link to web with color indexes so you can choose yours! Make some effort and change it to you color - u got comment in code 'here is color black!!

Comment: My apologies, when I tried for the grey color, I must have picked the wrong color.  So after your last comment I changed the separation row color to black and it worked.  Thanks for all your help and insightful information.  Much appreciated, sorry for my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions for StopRow aren't clear. Do you want to set StopRow when the cell has a conditional formatting rule or simply when it has a different format than the default ? A cell may have a rule but it may not be applied. Anyway, the function presented [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/CFColors.htm) is something you might find of use.

Copy the ActiveCondition function somewhere in a module and then change your for loop like so:

```
For i = 6 To StopRow
    If ActiveCondition(Cells(i,3))=0 Then StopRow=i : Exit For
    Cells(i, 3).Value = MasterValue
Next
```

If you want to check for change in font color that didn't come from conditional formatting then you'd need an extra line:

```
 For i = 6 To StopRow
        If ActiveCondition(Cells(i,3))=0 Then StopRow=i : Exit For
        If Cells(1,3).Font.ColorIndex=0 Then StopRow=i : Exit For 
        Cells(i, 3).Value = MasterValue
    Next
```

There are more elegant ways to do this but this solution is the easiest to implement in your code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The StopRow was just supposed to go the end of the column to where the last cell that contained a value, but now as you can see in the image, when it comes to a cell with color it stops instead of continuing on to the actual very last cell(with no background color)  Not worried about font color at this time.  I tried your solution and I've looked at the Active Condition document, and I thought there's a way more simpler way than having to include large function modules like that, I don't remember how.  I think it was just a FormatCondition = false or something along those lines,?? Not sure

Comment: FormatConditions is a Collection Object so it would have the .Count property. You could use it to stop your program whenever Cells(x,y).FormatConditions.Count=0 I think. I haven't tested this. But by now I trust you've had sufficient answers to know where to go from here.